# Best Way to extract first Char in a string C#

Tags: c#, regex

Is the following code is the ideal way to get the letter e which is the first char in the string

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string x = "334etsd23";
        var i = x[Regex.Match(x, @"^\d+").ToString().Count()];
        Console.WriteLine(i); // i gives e and works well 

    }
}
```

Comment: You could also try `x.FirstOrDefault(char.IsLetter)`, but I leave the benchmarking for you :)

Comment: Your question is confusing. `e` is not the first char in the string. It's the first *letter* in the string. Every element in a string is a char.

Comment: @itsme86 sorry you're correct yes I should have mentioned letter not Char

Comment: @RenéVogt , thanks for the answer it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var firstLetter = myString.FirstOrDefault(char.IsLetter);
```

This way you're not running a regex on the entire string.